# Отъезжаешь в далёкие края — в центр Санкт-Петербурга то бишь(,) — возьми с собою телефон

Tags: запятые

Если бы не было вставки, то, так как союз *если* пропущен, нужно было бы писать так:

> Отъезжаешь в далёкие края — возьми с собою телефон.

Но если я вставку-тире делаю, то надо вот так, без запятой?

> Отъезжаешь в далёкие края — в центр Санкт-Петербурга то бишь(,) — возьми с собою телефон.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение:

*Отъезжаешь в далёкие края (в центр Санкт-Петербурга то бишь) — возьми с собою телефон*.

Если пропущен союз ЕСЛИ, обязательно тире, а если использовать вставку с тире, то будет некорректно выглядеть.

Поэтому либо первый вариант, либо с союзом ЕСЛИ и запятой:

*Если отъезжаешь в далёкие края — в центр Санкт-Петербурга то бишь, — возьми с собою телефон*.

Comment: Максим, по правилам решайте (вариант с тире). ПАС, Розенталь...  Решить не трудно, сложнее в правило вписаться.

Answer (score 0):

**NEW!** **Решение 1 (по вставке)**

*Отъезжаешь в далёкие края — **в центр Санкт-Петербурга то бишь, —** возьми с собою телефон.*

Запятую нужно сместить направо, тогда вводное сообщение будет относиться **к первой части**. Но в правилах **нет такого варианта**, ссылку не найти.

**NEW!** **Решение 2 (по блокам, правило Лопатина)**

Отъезжаешь в далёкие края — **в центр Санкт-Петербурга то бишь,** — // возьми с собою телефон.

Здесь **два блока**: тире ставим в первой части (присоединение), а между блоками **ставим единый знак.**

Comment: Мне вообще-то ПРАВИЛО нужно, а не примеры.   Как-то уже неловко по образцам решать, в наше-то время.  А союз ЕСЛИ при чем? Здесь нет такого союза, но есть обусловленные отношения.  Будьте на уровне)

Comment: У Розенталя без вставки тире в этом предложении не будет. А у нас бессоюзная связь, без вставки ставится тире. Примеры разные.  Запятые могут быть, а могут не быть.

Comment: Извините, у Лео списала.

Comment: У "обеих".......

Comment: Зря! Интересно было поговорить) Театр!  Ладно... Я как будто сама себе доказываю. Художественный прием.